# std::cout with Android NDK on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, android-ndk

I am using std::cout in my c++ code running in VisualStudio 2015 for Android NDK.
But nothing gets printed in visual studio debugger. Is there a way to redirect to visualstudio everything for std::cout when debugging android ndk app? I saw some suggestions to redirect std::cout for Windows but nothing for Android when using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Android documentaion](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)

> By default, the Android system sends stdout and stderr (System.out and System.err) output to /dev/null. In processes that run the Dalvik VM.
>
> You can have the system write a copy of the output to the log file. In this case, the system writes the messages to the log using the log tags stdout and stderr, both with priority I.
>
> To route the output in this way, you stop a running emulator/device instance and then use the shell command setprop to enable the redirection of output. Here's how you do it:

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
$ adb shell start
```

Comment: yes, i ve seen that suggestion but i am not using ndk-build environment. The question is specific to new Visual Studio 2015 android compiler/debugger.